# Finding CDF from density function

Tags: probability, integration, density-function

Let $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 8xy\mathbb{1}_D(x,y)$$ with $D=\{0<x<y<1\}$

I want to find $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$, I do this by integrating:

$$ F_{X,Y}(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^y 8 x y dxdy$$
However now I think I misunderstand because I set up the integral on $D$ in this way: 
$$ F_{X,Y}(x,y) = \int_{x}^1 \int_{0}^y 8xydxdy$$ 
This is because x is between 0 and y and y is between x and 1, however I get the wrong result. Is there a mistake in the boundaries of the integral?

Comment: Write the CDF as $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^y\int_{-\infty}^x 8uv\,1_{0<u<v<1}\,du\,dv$ and continue.

Comment: @StubbornAtom In this way I am getting the same boundaries just with u and v instead of x,y. What am I missing?

Comment: @qcc101 Have a look to the link I´ve posted above and try to comprehend the answers.

Comment: @qcc101 It is confusing to use $x,y$ as dummy variables in the integral, which is itself a function of $x,y$.